# How do you find the latest supported version of a package in official repositories?

Tags: centos, package-management

Let's say I want to install a package in my CentOS server. The package I want to install is MariaDB or Redis,  or any other 3rd party package.

Is there a way to find it in the official repository of CentOS ?
I found the official repository is http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7  (correct me if I'm wrong though)

Also, apart from that, is there a yum command that can help me get that information ?

Comment: `yum list <package name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yum` will tell you about what’s available in the configured repositories (which include, by default, the official repositories):

```
$ yum search mariadb
======================================================= N/S matched: mariadb =======================================================
mariadb-bench.x86_64 : MariaDB benchmark scripts and data
mariadb-devel.i686 : Files for development of MariaDB/MySQL applications
mariadb-devel.x86_64 : Files for development of MariaDB/MySQL applications
mariadb-embedded.i686 : MariaDB as an embeddable library
mariadb-embedded.x86_64 : MariaDB as an embeddable library
mariadb-embedded-devel.i686 : Development files for MariaDB as an embeddable library
mariadb-embedded-devel.x86_64 : Development files for MariaDB as an embeddable library
mariadb-libs.i686 : The shared libraries required for MariaDB/MySQL clients
mariadb-libs.x86_64 : The shared libraries required for MariaDB/MySQL clients
mariadb-server.x86_64 : The MariaDB server and related files
mariadb.x86_64 : A community developed branch of MySQL
mariadb-test.x86_64 : The test suite distributed with MariaD

$ yum info mariadb
Available Packages
Name        : mariadb
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 5.5.65
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 8.7 M
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
Summary     : A community developed branch of MySQL
URL         : http://mariadb.org
License     : GPLv2 with exceptions and LGPLv2 and BSD
Description : MariaDB is a community developed branch of MySQL.
            : MariaDB is a multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database server.
            : It is a client/server implementation consisting of a server daemon (mysqld)
            : and many different client programs and libraries. The base package
            : contains the standard MariaDB/MySQL client programs and generic MySQL files.
```

You can also use `yum list` to get a brief summary of available versions and the repositories providing them.

Redis isn’t available in the official CentOS repositories, but it is available in EPEL:

```
$ sudo yum install -y epel-release
[...]

$ yum info redis
Available Packages
Name        : redis
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 3.2.12
Release     : 2.el7
Size        : 544 k
Repo        : epel/x86_64
Summary     : A persistent key-value database
URL         : http://redis.io
License     : BSD
Description : Redis is an advanced key-value store. It is often referred to as a data
            : structure server since keys can contain strings, hashes, lists, sets and
            : sorted sets.
[...]
```

A good source of newer versions of certain packages is [Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/); for example [MariaDB 10.3](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-mariadb103/) is available there.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. yum info is quite usefull. It will also tell you if you have the package installed, or if there are versions presents in separate repositories.  Thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

The definition of **official** or **supported** depends on the repository you include. To be precise, **official** is misleading, since there is obviously no centralized **office** overarching all repositories.

The term **supported** depends also on the repo, but let's assume a common understanding here. Then everything you install with `yum install _package_` should be considered up-to-date, supported, and recommended by the package maintainers.

This is a very formal point of view. In real life package maintainers from "official" repositories tend to employ a more conservative policy. Most often that leads to situations that don't break things, but you may or may not be a step behind the latest features. Those are available in personal or project specific repositories that are not considered "official". Those two types blur and sometimes overlap.

All what is said here applies more or less to any package manager and is not exclusive to CentOS.